# Deploying WebGoat in Firefox

Tags: java, security, firefox, tomcat

I have just downloaded WebGoat 5.4

I have unzipped the file and clicked on the webgoat.bat file.

However, when I type in [http://localhost/WebGoat/attack] in Firefox, a warning by IIS crops up saying that the resurce does not exist.

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to install any other software to get it running?

I have some websites deployed on IIS.  Do they affect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firefox** is not an **web application server** to deploy your **WebGoat**. You'll need an **Apache Tomcat** instance to be able to use **WebGoat**.

Here is a [link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/WebGoat_Installation) which will help you in setting up your **WebGoat**.

Comment: Thanks :)  I got it running.